# Force line break after item (with label)

Tags: lists

I have looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29518/26514) solution and while it works for items without labels in my case I have the `labeling` environment (to be more specific: `\begin{labeling}{alligator} ... \end{labelling}`) and obviously a labeling list without labels doesn't make much sense.

Currently it looks like this (right part is cut off since it's not related to the issue):

[image]

Initially (before I added the **Python 3.4** item) it looked okay but then I noticed that due to the length of some of the labels things weren't "looking" as if they had the same alignment especially since my labels are also **bold** which makes the issue even more visible.

I would like to feed a line break and get the following result:

[image]

I've just started learning about defining custom commands (or redefining present ones) and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to do that for the `\item[...]` command. Adding `\mbox{}\\` after every single item is a lot of unnecessary work and even if I didn't have to do it (that is another solution for my problem is present) I would still like to know how to handle such commands.

I have tried

```
\let\OldItem\item
\renewcommand{\item}[1]{\OldItem[#1]\mbox{}\\}
```

but it results in a horrible mess (plus it doesn't fix my issue at all):

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Can you add a MWE?

Comment: Could you provide a *complete*, minimal example of your setup? Specific to `\let`ting commands that have optional arguments. See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764)

Comment: You might like [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en).  In particular look for the `nextline` style in the docs.

Comment: May the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359306/creating-codebook-with-justified-entries-using-hfill-or-other-method  can help.

Comment: @moewe You are right. It's not a duplicate. Answer from gernot fits perfectly although I would prefer not to create a custom environment (which I'm completely not familiar with).

Comment: @rbaleksandar: I agree it's not a real duplicate, though close. I've posted another solution, as an answer to the ‘duplicate question’ since your question was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution almost works, you just have to treat the argument of `\item` as an optional argument in square brackets. It is probably better not to redefine `\item` globally but to do it only where needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\OldItem\item
\newcommand\NewItem[1][]{\OldItem[#1]\mbox{}\\}
\newenvironment{mydescription}%
  {\begin{description}\let\item\NewItem}%
  {\end{description}}
\begin{document}
\begin{mydescription}
\item[C] for evaluation of bla bla bla
\item[C++] the main language for ble ble ble
\item[Pyton 3.4] for data evaluation of blu blu blu
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. I didn't think I have to define a whole environment for this. Is there a way to avoid this? (I don't mind using your solution at all)

Comment: @rbaleksandar What exactly is bad in defining a new environment to encapsulate the changes? Alternatively, you can use `\let\OldItem\item\renewcommand\item[1][]{\OldItem[#1]\mbox{}\\}` in the preamble, but this will affect all lists throughout your document; and `\item` commands are used in many places.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do this using the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\lipsum{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2em]
\item[C]\lipsum
\item[C++]\lipsum
\item[Python 3.4]\lipsum
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]