# Two questions about the package enumitem

Tags: beamer, enumitem

I am not very good in LaTeX, so sorry for my silly question. ;)

I've just added the package `enumitem` to my tex-file for having a line break after each label of `\begin{description}`. That works very fine!

Problem 1)
I just saw, that the "dots" of my `\begin{itemize}` items disappeared

Problem 2)
Without the use of the package `enumitem` the labels of the description are colored. How can I get this colored labels while using the package?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{
    style=nextline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{description}
    \item[Item1] Description of item 1.
    \item[Item2] Description of item 2.
\end{description}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Where are
    \item the dots?
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as know, beamer manages lists its own way, and doesn't cooperate very well with enumitem.

Comment: The solution (`\item[label]\mbox{}\\ text`) proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359467/134144) should work for your `beamer` document as well.

Comment: `enumitem` and `beamer` shouldn't be used together.

Comment: @mrbela Can you make a sketch how the result should look like?